# How to check if event.target matches querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

This is my Javascript:

```
const addButton       = document.querySelector(".add");
const removeButtons   = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target == addButton) {
        addFields(event);
    } else if (event.target.className == removeButtons[0].className) { // Is there a better way?
        removeFields(event);
    }
});
```

Is there a simpler way to check if a selector matches an `event.target`?

I would like to do this:

`if (event.target == removeButtons)`

However, this doesn't work here because there are multiple `removeButtons` (hence the selector `querySelectorAll`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `event.target.matches('.add')` and `event.target.matches('.remove')` (it can accept any selector string, very flexible). If you're using event delegation like you're doing, *often* there's no need to get a `querySelectorAll` collection beforehand

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I've used `.matches()` before. But what if I don't want to use CSS classes but selectors only?

Comment: A CSS class with a `.` in front of it *is* a selector string. I'm not sure what you're asking? I guess you can use other attributes instead, like tag names or data attributes or IDs, if you want

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is a `constant`. I am typically storing my selectors in constants (as in the example above) since I don't want to repeat CSS classes multiple times in my code. My hope was that there's a way to check if an `event.target` matches a selector stored in a constant. But it seems there is no easy way to do that...

Comment: Yeah, you're storing a `NodeList` in a variable (the `const` isn't important), but NodeLists don't have anything that lets you extract the selector used from a collection. You could make a method that turns an element into a selector string, and then call `.matches` with that string, but that's pretty weird